# CSS Element Ignores Image In Padding

Tags: html, css

So, I have a web page with css, one of the elements has an image and text. The image is aligned to left, and it is extending past the parent element's padding.

The parent element respects text, and extends as more text is added, but it lets the image go past without extending.

This is what it looks like:

---

[image]

This is what I want:

---

[image: What I want]

Basically, I want the content element to expand not only with the text, but also with  elements too. Finally, the source:
http://pastebin.com/VY3P9CtJ - CSS
http://pastebin.com/7sSbuvrC - HTML

Comment: Is the image you're wanting to extend a flat background color, or is it actually an image whose height you want to conditionally crop?

Comment: without code its a case of mind reading how to fix it.

Comment: @JoshC just uploaded both, with pastebin. Sorry for not doing that first... I accidentally clicked submit.

Comment: @Ryan I want to extend the content element so the image fits without going past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do inline styles for clarity, but change to the following:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Books</h1>
  <img src='images/vol1.jpg' style='float:left;' width='300px'/>
  <p>text text text text text text text</p><div style='clear:both'/><hr/><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I prefer seperate css documents, but I will convert to inline when I ask questions in the future.

Comment: Actually, separating your HTML from your CSS is fine when asking.  I just didn't want to go to the trouble of making a fiddle for something small.  Good luck!

Comment: All is good! I have been using clear:both with <br/>, and having good results. Thanks again for the quick reply!